# Minify Plain CSS From "src" Folder to "lib" and/or "dist" Folder

Tags: spfx-tooling

I have plain.css at /src. It would be nice if webpack or gulp would minify and copy plain.css to /lib and become available as an external resource set in config. Similar to how .js modules can be included from /lib as an external resource.

Is this possible with drop 4?

Answer (score 1):

From a dev on the team - Currently, CSS files can be copied if you configure the copy-static-assets task, but – correct – they won’t be minimized. However, if you change the extension from .css to .scss and reference the CSS that way, it’ll get minimized because it’ll get processed by the SCSS compiler. SCSS is a superset of CSS, so all valid CSS is valid SCSS.